# Lodash find a value within an array from an array of values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have the following array:

```
var data = [
    'Value1',
    'Value2',
    'Value3'
];
```

Using another array, how would I get a truthy value if a value was found within the data array?

```
var dataLookup = [
    'Value1',
    'Value2'
]
```

I know that in lodash I could do the following to look for a single value;

```
_.includes(data, 'Value1'); // true
```

I would like to pass an array of values to look for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `some()` to check if one value from `dataLookup` is inside `data` and if it is it will return `true` if one isn't it will return `false`

```js
var data = ['Value1','Value2','Value3'];
var dataLookup = ['Value1','Value2']

var result = dataLookup.some((e) => {return data.indexOf(e) != -1});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Lodash equivalent: `var result = _.every(dataLookup, _.partial(_.includes, data));`

Comment: Thanks for that, however I just want to return true if one of the values from `dataLookup` exists within `data`.

Comment: @KarlBateman You can use `.some()` in place of `.every()` for that.

Comment: Thank you @NenadVracar for your time.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thanks for that, please post that as an answer so I may accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [difference()](https://lodash.com/docs#difference) and [equal()](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) to check if some values from the `data` array exists from the `dataLookup` array.

```
var found = !_.(data).difference(dataLookup).isEqual(data);
```

```js
var data = [
    'Value1',
    'Value2',
    'Value3'
];

var dataLookup = [
    'Value1',
    'Value2'
];

var found = !_(data).difference(dataLookup).isEqual(data);

console.log(found);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.12.0/lodash.js"></script>
```